# why getting response as an html in string request alamofire swift?

Tags: ios, swift, string, alamofire, response

hello I am using alamofire and swift 4 and I am trying to make a request to get some data from the api from server, and the response should be only a string including some number, when I get the response it gives me an html , I dont know why its not coming because in android app it comes correctly  the same url and same headers

here my code of alamofire :

```
let getBalanceUrlStr = URLs.URL_GET_BALANCE + userDefaul.getLoggedUserDetails().emailStr!
    print(getBalanceUrlStr)
    let headers = ["Authorization":"bearer " + self.userDefaul.getLoggedUserDetails().accessToken!]
    print(headers)
    AFManager.strRequestGETURL(getBalanceUrlStr, headers: headers, success: { (response) in
        //progressHUD.hide()
        print("responseee  \(response)")
        self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()

    }) { (error) in
        //progressHUD.hide()
        print(error)
        self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()

    }
```

the AFManager is class for managing the requests, here the request code

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class AFManager : NSObject{
class func strRequestGETURL(_ strURL : String, headers : [String : String]?, success:@escaping (JSON) -> Void, failure:@escaping (Error) -> Void){

    Alamofire.request(strURL, method: .get, encoding: URLEncoding.default , headers: headers).responseString { (responseObject) -> Void in

        print(responseObject)

        if responseObject.result.isSuccess {
            let resJson = JSON(responseObject.result.value!)
            success(resJson)
        }

        if responseObject.result.isFailure {
            let error : Error = responseObject.result.error!
            failure(error)
        }

    }
}
```

here are some of what I get

```
responseee  <!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>

    <title>The resource cannot be found.</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

    <style>

     body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 

     p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}

     b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}

     H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }

     H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }

     pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}

     .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}

     .version {color: gray;}

     .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}

     .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }

     @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {

      pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }

     }

     @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {

      pre { width: 280px; }

     }

    </style>

</head>



<body bgcolor="white">



        <span><H1>Server Error in '/' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>



        <h2> <i>The resource cannot be found.</i> </h2></span>



        <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">



        <b> Description: </b>HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. &nbsp;Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

        <br><br>



        <b> Requested URL: </b>/Website/Index<br><br>



        <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>



        <b>Version Information:</b>&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.2623.0



        </font>



</body>

</html>
```

please help me what the problem could be ? thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like your URL is misformed in iOS as the HTML returned is a generic server error page.

Comment: no the url the same I printed and its same, I checked it

Answer (score 1):

The response is clearly telling you what's wrong:

> HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Compare your `getBalanceUrlStr` with the URLs you're using on Android.

Comment: no the url the same I printed and its same, I checked it

Comment: Two more things to check: 1) the server logs, especially comparing a request from Android and one from iOS. 2) make sure all HTTP headers are set identically on both platforms.

Comment: I check all things you told me and there are fine, and still get the whole html page but the page now not HTTP 404 page , it shows the real website page I can get the string response yet

Answer (score 0):

Please try this It may helps to you.

```
Alamofire.request(requestURL, method: .get, parameters: param as? Parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.methodDependent, headers: nil).responseJSON { (responseJson) in
            print("Response : \(responseJson)")
}
```

Other wise use `JSONEncoding.default` in-steed of  `URLEncoding.methodDependent`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the URL that you're trying to fetch from, as you get a "Resource not found" response.

- Most of the HTML responses that you get after a request, are due to problems with the URL(It's probably misformed somewhere)
- Print the URL in your debug terminal and try accessing it yourself.
- Finally, make sure that it isn't a restricted domain which has restrained access from selective networks

Hope this helps!

Comment: all things I checked it seems fine? now I dont get "Resource not found" response, but I am getting the html page